# Asymptotics of a sequences of integrals

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I would like to know the asymptotics of the following sequences of integrals:
$$   I_n = \int _0
                ^{+ \infty}
                e^{-t} \left ( \dfrac{t}{1 + t} \right )^n
                \ dt
$$

I have tried using Laplace method ou saddle node method, but I have been unable to conclude anything.

I have tried to find out the behaviour using a software computation. Here is what I found:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \\
        n & I_n & - \ln(I_n)
        \\
        \hline
        1 = 2^0      & 1.9269472 \cdot 10^{-1}   &    1.646648079928304
        \\
        \hline
        2 = 2^1      & 8.7215768 \cdot 10^{-2}   &    2.4393701372220464
        \\
        \hline
        4 = 2^2      & 2.6524946 \cdot 10^{-2}   &    3.629669596451481
        \\
        \hline
        8 = 2^3      & 4.7442047 \cdot 10^{-3}   &    5.35083146190712
        \\
        \hline
        16 = 2^4     & 4.1306898 \cdot 10^{-4}   &    7.7918959541372
        \\
        \hline
        32 = 2^5     & 1.3310510 \cdot 10^{-5}   &   11.226956600782769
        \\
        \hline
        64 = 2^6     & 1.0697730 \cdot 10^{-7}   &   16.05064913913718
        \\
        \hline
        128 = 2^7    & 1.2206772 \cdot 10^{-10}  &   22.826445101120278
        \\
        \hline
        256 = 2^8    & 8.8802107 \cdot 10^{-15}  &   32.35495110837777
        \\
        \hline
        512 = 2^9    & 1.3241607 \cdot 10^{-20}  &   45.77092301635973
        \\
        \hline
        1024 = 2^{10}   & 8.1182635 \cdot 10^{-29}  &   64.6808514171555
        \\
        \hline
        2048 = 2^{11}   & 2.1076879 \cdot 10^{-40}  &   91.3578121482943
        \\
        \hline
        4096 = 2^{12}   & 9.3011756 \cdot 10^{-57}  &  129.01720949348262
        \\
        \hline
        8192 = 2^{13}   & 7.3886987 \cdot 10^{-80}  &  182.2068558012616
        \\
        \hline
        16384 = 2^{14}  & 1.7003331 \cdot 10^{-112} &  257.358706225986
        \\
        \hline
        32768 = 2^{15}  & 1.2703122 \cdot 10^{-158} &  363.5691819464147
        \\
        \hline
        65536 = 2^{16}  & 7.9749999 \cdot 10^{-224} &  513.7027491850932
        \\
        \hline
        131072 = 2^{17} & 5.2817088 \cdot 10^{-316} &  725.9526396990342
        \\
        \hline
        262144 = 2^{18} & 2.4716651 \cdot 10^{-446} & 1026.0480594180656
        \\
        \hline
        524288 = 2^{19} & 1.2878115 \cdot 10^{-630} & 1450.3756643021711
        \\
        \hline
    \end{array}
\end{equation}
From this tabular, it seems that $\ln I_n \sim - 2 \sqrt{n}$.

**Is there any method to study such sequences of integrals?**

Answer (score 5):

The integral
$$I_n=\int_0^\infty e^{f(n,t)}\,dt,\;\;f(n,t)=n\ln t-n\ln(1+t)-t,$$
has a saddle point at $t^*$ where $\partial f(n,t)/\partial t=0$,
$$t^\ast=-\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+4n}.$$
For $n\rightarrow\infty$ the integral tends to
$$I_n\rightarrow e^{f(n,t^\ast)} = e^{-2\sqrt{n}+{\cal O}(1)},$$
so $\ln I_n\rightarrow -2\sqrt{n}$, as found numerically.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume the following conjecture:

> Let $h: \mathbb{R}^+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.
> Let also $g_n: \mathbb{R}^+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $\mathcal{C}^2$ function over $\mathbb{R}^+$, depending of an positive integer $n$, with a unique maximum $\mathcal{U}_n$ such that $g_n''(\mathcal{U}_n) < 0$.
> Therefore, we have the following estimation:
> $$ \int _0
>         ^{+ \infty}
>         h(t) e^{- g_n(t)}
>         \ dt
>    \underset{n \longrightarrow + \infty}{\sim}
>    h(\mathcal{U}_n)
>    \cdot
>    \sqrt { \dfrac{2 \pi}{- g_n''(\mathcal{U}_n)} }
>    \cdot
>    e^{g_n(\mathcal{U}_n)}
>    \ .
> $$

This is a little adaptation to the classical Laplace method (see [Wikipedia page on Laplace method, section "Other formulation"][1]

In our case, as pointed out by Carlo Beenakker, we have $h(t) = 1$,
$g_n(t) = t - n \ln t + n \ln(1 + t)$ and $\mathcal{U}_n = \dfrac{\sqrt{4n + 1} - 1}{2}$. So, we finaly find that
$$ I_n
   \underset{n \longrightarrow + \infty}{\sim}
   \sqrt{e \pi} n^{\frac{1}{4}} e^{-2 \sqrt{n}}
   \ .
$$
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method